# Can I combine REST classes and Static Resources in simple Meecrowave project?

Tags: java, rest, web-applications

I have two maven Meecrowave projects that I would like to combine.
- First project is a simple class, with a main method:
- The second project only contains static html files.

To avoid getting XSS or CSRF errors, I would like to combine the two projects.

I have combined my java classes and html/js files in one project
java in src/main/java
HTML/JS in src/main/resources/www

I've tried setting the "webapp" in the POM configuration file.  This seems to get overriden by the classes scanned for REST decorators.

```
public static void main(String... args) throws Exception {
    try (final Meecrowave meecrowave = new Meecrowave().bake()) {
        new Scanner(System.in).nextLine();
    } finally {

    }
}
```

My REST Controller looks like this:

```
@Path("modules")
@ApplicationScoped
@Produces("application/json")
public class MyApplication {
...
    @GET
    public List<Module> getModules() {
        return modules;
    }
}
```

The Maven POM file contains the plugin as shown below:

```
<build>
    <resources>
        <resource>
            <directory>${frontend.base}</directory>
        </resource>
    </resources>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.meecrowave</groupId>
        <artifactId>meecrowave-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>${mw.version}</version>
        <configuration>
        <httpPort>8082</httpPort>
        <webResourceCached>false</webResourceCached>
        <webapp>${frontend.base}/www</webapp>
        </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

I would expect to be able to browse to my HTML files:
http://localhost:8082/

I would expect to be able to browse to my Java REST resources:
http://localhost:8082/modules

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default the jaxrs application is bound on /* so overlaps with resources, try adding @ApplicationPath("/api") or so to pove your rest endpoints under api subcontext and it should work.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I've edited my post to show my controller, with the @Path annotation.  I'm probably not supposed to do this.

Comment: You didnt add an Application class like https://github.com/rmannibucau/rblog/blob/master/src/main/java/com/github/rmannibucau/rblog/jaxrs/RBlogApplication.java ?